# Getting content from another page with javascript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I was trying to perform client side validation for `captcha`. For that I need to get the response from an external `url`. I used the below `javascript` code for that.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function captcha_check()
  {
    var code = document.getElementById("captcha").value;
    alert(code);
    var url = "http://www.opencaptcha.com/validate.php?img='.$captcha_name.'.jpgx&ans="+code;
    alert(url);
    $.get(url,function(data,status){
      alert(data);
      if(data == "fail")
      {
        document.getElementById("captcha_error").style.display = "block";
        return false;
      }
      else
      {
        return true;
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

But the code is not working. The `url` and `code` are alerting correctly. But the `javascript` stops executing the jquery function to get content from the `url` and skipping the remaining steps in the function.

Please help me find out what's wrong with my code.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: are any errors reported in the console?

Comment: No. There is no error displayed on javascript console

Answer (score 2):

Cross domain ajax request can't be done unless the response accept request from all domains.
Also i don't think client side validation for captcha can be called "secure".

More info:
[Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/)

Comment: [link](http://www.opencaptcha.com/validate.php?img=aDf112.jpgx&ans=asdf)

This link will return either fail or success. Is there anyway to get that on my page with javascript. :(

Comment: No with normal page rights. Only if you have specific extensions permissions (you run the code inside a chrome extension). But as i said ... this is not secure... its like not having captcha at all. Javascript is not a safe way to built security.

Answer (score 0):

There are security restrictions on cross domain ajax calls.

Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

I tried a your code from my location and chrome returns:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.opencaptcha.com/validate.php?img=%27.$captcha_name.%27.jpgx&ans=hi. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.

which is what you expect with cross domain calls like this.

This is why your code is failing.

Comment: http://www.opencaptcha.com/validate.php?img=aDf112.jpgx&ans=asdf

This link will return either fail or success. Is there anyway to get that on my page with javascript. :(

Comment: With Javascript alone there is not much I can suggest on this. One way it could be done, is the use of a server side component like a Java Servlet that would make the call and then return the result to your javascript via an ajax call. As the servlet would reside on your domain, the ajax call would succeed, and the server side code doesn't have the same restrictions.